# Debian (Buster) Nextcloud Error While Trying To Create Admin User - Access Denied

Tags: debian, mysql, mariadb, nextcloud

I am performing a manual installation of Nextcloud on my personal machine running Debian (Buster).

I've followed all of the steps of [the instructions](https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/18/admin_manual/installation/source_installation.html), up to the point where it wants me to complete installation by running either the [graphical installation wizard](https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/18/admin_manual/installation/installation_wizard.html) or by [using the command line with the occ command](https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/18/admin_manual/installation/command_line_installation.html).

I have tried both methods, multiple times, multiple different ways. Always ends up with the same result:

[image: screenshot]

At first, the problem was because I did not set up the mariadb 'root@localhost' user properly. Fixed that.

I've tried manually adding the "oc_nxtadmin" username to the database... and Nextcloud just tries to use "oc_nxtadmin1" instead.

I saw some solutions that suggested the problem was that I was using the 'root@localhost' user for mariadb. Tried other usernames. Granted all permissions to whichever username I was using for access to the database, same problem.

I've reinstalled mariadb, making sure that the databases were fresh also, a couple of times just to make sure I had everything configured properly.

When looking for solutions to this issue, most of the search results are focused on getting past the 'root@localhost' issues. The issue at hand here is at least one step past that.

Thank you in advance for any assistance.